# Creating a multidimentional array from preexisting arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Firstly hello.
 I am trying to create a basic calculator of sorts that transfers my array into a cvs file.
The problem that I came upon is that when I try to create a nested array in ruby with pre-existing arrays I get a 1D array where all of the values in each row are stuck someway

```
whole_array=[[part1],[part2],[part3]]
puts whole_array[1][1]
return part1[1]
```

When this is invoked it  does not output anything with the puts command yet part1,part2,part3 all being arrays have a value
The only thing I can think of is that ruby forgets that those variables are and puts them in as strings

Comment: There are no multi-dimensional arrays in Ruby (unless you count `Matrix` from the standard library), just arrays of arrays and such.

Comment: What are `part1`, `part2`, and `part3` here and what exactly are you expecting `whole_array` to look like?

Comment: `whole_array[1][1] = (whole_array[1])[1] =  ([part2])[1] => nil`. Have you forgotten that Ruby's indexes begin at zero? If `arr = [4]`, `arr[0] => 4` and `arr[1] #=> nil`, as `arr[1]` references the second element of `arr` (which only contains one element). As mu points out, we don't know what `part2` is. Presumably it is a variable or a method. If you meant it to be a literal, perhaps it should be `"part2"` or `:part2`.

Comment: all of the parts are arrays also.I found the solution for this.My problem was that I was creating a 3D array which [0][0] position had part1 array